# winner in giveaway command in discord.py

Tags: python, list, discord.py

I tried to make a giveaway in discord.py...

my code:

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def gstart(ctx,time,winners,prize):

    channel = ctx.channel

    embed = discord.Embed(title="Giveaway!",description=f"{prize}",color=random.choice(colors))
    embed.add_field(name="Hosted by:", value=ctx.author.mention)
    embed.set_footer(text=f"Ends {time} from now!")
    my_msg = await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)
    await my_msg.add_reaction("")

    d = time[-1]

    num = int(time[:-1])

    if d == "s":
        await asyncio.sleep(num)

    if d == "m":
        await asyncio.sleep(num * 60)

    if d == "h":
        await asyncio.sleep(num * 60 * 60)

    if d == "d":
        await asyncio.sleep(num * 60 * 60 * 24)

    winners_number = int(winners[:-1])
    new_msg = await channel.fetch_message(my_msg.id)

    users_mention = []
    for i in range(winners_number):
      users = await new_msg.reactions[0].users().flatten()
      users.pop(users.index(bot.user))
      winner = random.choice(users)
      users_mention.append(winner.mention)
    await ctx.send(f"Congratulations {users_mention} you won the giveaway !")
```

my error:
Its can do 2 the same winners...
I can  do its cant be the same winners?
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: instead of looping over `winners_number` [use `random.sample(users, winners_number)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample)

Comment: raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'mention'

Comment: random.sample gives you a list of the users, if you want the mentions from them you could loop over it, try printing the results of variables you aren't sure what they are or `print(type(X))` can be helpful for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

u should add

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def gstart(ctx,time,winners,prize):

    channel = ctx.channel

    embed = discord.Embed(title="Giveaway!",description=f"{prize}",color=random.choice(colors))
    embed.add_field(name="Hosted by:", value=ctx.author.mention)
    embed.set_footer(text=f"Ends {time} from now!")
    my_msg = await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)
    await my_msg.add_reaction("")

    d = time[-1]

    num = int(time[:-1])

    if d == "s":
        await asyncio.sleep(num)

    if d == "m":
        await asyncio.sleep(num * 60)

    if d == "h":
        await asyncio.sleep(num * 60 * 60)

    if d == "d":
        await asyncio.sleep(num * 60 * 60 * 24)

    winners_number = int(winners[:-1])
    new_msg = await channel.fetch_message(my_msg.id)

    users_mention = []
    for i in range(winners_number):
      users = await new_msg.reactions[0].users().flatten()
      users.pop(users.index(bot.user))
      winner = random.choice(users)
      users_mention.append(winner.mention)
      users.remove(winner) # added this so next time the user wont be in list.
    await ctx.send(f"Congratulations {users_mention} you won the giveaway !")
```